# Curl - error 60 - GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, facebook, curl, guzzle

What can cause an error 60 for cURL? Certificate is identical to the one used in local environment but raises an error on production.

---

(original problem)

So I'm trying to integrate `Illuminate\Socialize` into my app, with a Facebook login. It all seems to work out fine locally, and on my production server I obtain the following error:

```
RequestException in MultiAdapter.php line 234:
[curl] (#60) See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
for an explanation of cURL errors [url]

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={client_id}
&client_secret={secret}&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

It seems that error 60 comes from a certificate error.
A few points:

- My Google module works in production as expected.
- I'm on shared hosting.
- The redirect-uri is authorized

Any directions on a solution would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit:
I managed to make it work twisting `Adapter\Curl\CurlFactory.php`, adding after `curl_init`

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Although it is only a quick-fix as it looks insecure. On the same location, I tried adding

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../cacert.pem');
```

(+verifypeer to true), but it has no effect... anybody?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the same problem as in [Guzzle and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582091/guzzle-and-https) - please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588396/413531 and check if explicitly providing a newly downloaded cacert.pem file solves your issue (double check that the path to the file is valid!)

Comment: This is indeed how I solved similar issues on the production server. I assumed error was coming from a bug from Socialize, but it looks like I made a mistake. Will try again with a newer version of Socialize and see what's going on.